# Can we represent a line of length equal to irrational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From Euclid's postulate we know that "A straight line segment can be drawn using any two points ". Now  Let us suppose, we take a unit base and a unit perpendicular, so we have two definite points on a plane. From Euclid's postulate we can draw a line segment, but pythagoras theorem tells us that the hypotensue should be of length root 2 which is a irrational number.

So how is it possible that to draw a line segment when we don't know where the other point lies. By taking approximation we will make the number rational.

Can we say that in such scenarios, a line doesn't connect two points rather there is a ray which tends to a hypothetical point. It looks analogous to taking limit where a tangent is approximation of a secant and here a line is an approximation of a ray.

Comment: Why do you say that we don't know where the other point lies?

Comment: Well we know that root 2 lies somewhere in between 1.4 and 1.5 but we don't know  the exact point from a reference position.

Comment: The other points maybe confusing here, sorry for that. It is better to say another decimal values.

Comment: But you can place the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. You don't need to know $\sqrt{2}$ to find them. But then, the distance between them *must* be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It doesn't matter the distance comes to irrational from distance formula or by hypotenuse of a right angled triangle, the problem is that a theoretical irrational length confined to two definite points. A irrational number can't be scaled and that's how I'm seeing the problem.

Comment: Only if the number is constructible by means defined by ancient Greek (straight unmarked edge & a compass), any other irrational is impossible to construct, because it is impossible to lie exactly on the real number line - since it doesn't exist actually,  (except by cheating, or hiding behind ambiguous concepts, such as (infinity, convergence, approximations, famous cuts. limit,intermediate theorem, ...etc), also the constructible numbers are very dense and don't allow any more numbers in between, those I call them fake numbers which is impossible to construct only one of them rigorously

Comment: @bassamkarzeddin. Thank you, my original confusion is now resolved. And sorry for not voting up your comment, I'm restricted :/

Answer (score 1):

Assume you don't know anything about rational vs. irrational, and are given the following problem: "Draw a line $\ell$, choose an arbitrary point $0\in\ell$ and another point $1\in\ell$. Where is the point that should get the label $\sqrt{2}$?" You would go ahead and find this point with a little construction, and without having any doubts that this is exactly the point you wanted.

Of course this construction lives in an ideal mathematical world, and we all know that the lines drawn with a pencil have a certain thickness, etc. But this is a completely other matter.

Concerning scaling: Given any two points $A$, $B\in\ell$ you can scale their distance $|AB|$ by a factor $\sqrt{2}$ using the three points you already have and drawing a few parallels.

Comment: When we take a rular and draw a line, we go through many irrational numbers but we can't stop our pen right at an irrational number, we could assert that a pen must not go further before reaching an irrational number (like while moving from 1.4 to 1.5, we will go through root(2)). But that can be done as how zeno's dichotomy paradox was solved. And so between two definite points which have an irrational length as per distance formula will not make a line segment between those two points, instead the ray will tend to length of root (2). That's all I'm seeing. Help me where I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Say that the segment in question is supposed to be between $A$ and $B$. Say your segment starts at $A$ and its length is some rational number $q < \sqrt{2}$. Then there will be space between the endpoint and $B$, and that doesn't make sense. You can't keep changing the length of the segment to make it bigger: each point either definitely belongs to it or definitely doesn't.

Comment: I never said that those two points are making a line segment and obviously on the same basis as you described. A line segment can't keep changing the length. But when we say that length is equal to an irrational number then it is necessary to say that the length must not be definite like an irrational number. I'm not saying that an irrational number is infinite, I'm saying that it is just indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to Euclids geometry the line do connect the two points. That it certainly says.

What it doesn't say and known not to be true is that two lines does need to be comensurable (that is you can take multiples of them and end up with equally long line). For example the diagonal in a square and the sides of the squares aren't.

Note that the numbers used then were only the natural numbers, so the problem with "knowing" where the points were was not a matter of numbers since the numbers available was definitely inadequate for the task anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitively represent some irrational numbers for example to represent $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ where $n$ is an integer, draw a rectangle whose sides has length $1$ and $n$, the diagonal has length $\sqrt{n^2+1}$.

To represent $\pi$, draw a circle of diameter $1$.